# How to add more liquidity (tokens for sale)?

Tags: solidity, tokens, pancakeswap

I'm a begineer doing some tests using an example token. I want to add more liquidity to pancake swap sale, so potential buyers could for example, buy it. Initially, I've added 10% of the total tokens (initial liquidity), and now I want to add another 70%. How do I do that, or it's not possible?

Also, what happens if those tokens are sent to either contract address or pancake router address?

Comment: if you are on the mainnet you can do that in the https://pancakeswap.finance/ portal. 
it's the liquidity tab.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime what if I defined the rate already and don't have enough to BNB to provide that amount for the liquidity?